# How to set int variable to number-number

Tags: java, variables, set

I'm pretty new to Java. I'm making a class for a card. The face is the number of the card, and can only be 1-13. I'm trying to validate it by setting f to 1-13. I wanted to simply do this:

```
public void setFace(int f)
   {

    f int >= 1 && f <= 13);
   }
```

Obviously, you can't do that. How do would I simply set f to the numbers 1-13? Thanks for any help!

Comment: this will not compile either

Comment: You're going about validation the wrong way. You should check whether the number is in the valid range and do something if it isn't, not set it equal to *all* the valid numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (f >= 1 && f <= 13) {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do in this way

```
public void setFace(int f) {

if(f < 1 || f > 13)
{
   throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid face value "+f+" face must be between 1-13");
}
}
```

Angelo